# how to close popup window without reloading the whole page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

am using page when click on delete it will open popup and ask for confirmation,now i want to close the popup when click on cancel but not to redirect to main page.below code is delete view in mvc...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" /> 
   @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
```

jquery code is

```
$(".deleteimage").click(function (e) {
        var url = $(this).parent().attr('href');
        $("#dialog-delete").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 180,
            width: 300,
            show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).load(url);
            },
            close: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        });
        $("#dialog-delete").dialog('open');

        return false;
    });
```

in index view am using this code..

```
  @(new HtmlString(@Ajax.ImageActionLink("../../Content/images/grid/Del.png", "Delete", "Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.TerminalID }, "deleteimage", new AjaxOptions
         {
             HttpMethod = "GET",
             InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
             UpdateTargetId = "targetdiv"
       })))
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to close a jQuery UI dialog you could use the close method:

```
$("#dialog-delete").dialog('close');
```